# XCode - Everything giving me a key/value compliance error?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

So, a Log In button was giving me an error, saying that there was a key/value compliance error, you know, the one where you're supposed to go and delete the outlets/actions and reconnect them. A simple fix, usually.  "Thread 1: "[<UIViewController 0x7fa33c10dbf0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key xyz"

But now, when I fix it, another one pops up. After I fixed the Log In button for my app, the Sign In button gave the same error. I disconnected all the outlets and actions for it, ran the app, the error was gone for a few seconds, until a NEW one popped up: one of the labels on the screen was giving the exact same error. Repeat, repeat, repeat. I keep getting this same error for everything I have. What's the deal?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From the error, the class of the `UIViewController` in Xib/Storyboard is `UIViewController` and not your custom class...